# How to conditionally remove items from a .NET collection

Tags: c#, .net, collections, extension-methods

I'm trying to write an extension method in .NET that will operate on a generic collection, and remove all items from the collection that match a given criteria.

This was my first attempt:

```
public static void RemoveWhere<T>(this ICollection<T> Coll, Func<T, bool> Criteria){
    foreach (T obj in Coll.Where(Criteria))
        Coll.Remove(obj);
}
```

However this throws an InvalidOperationException, "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute". Which does make sense, so I made a second attempt with a second collection variable to hold the items that need to be removed and iterate through that instead:

```
public static void RemoveWhere<T>(this ICollection<T> Coll, Func<T, bool> Criteria){
    List<T> forRemoval = Coll.Where(Criteria).ToList();

    foreach (T obj in forRemoval)
        Coll.Remove(obj);
}
```

This throws the same exception; I'm not sure I really understand why as 'Coll' is no longer the collection being iterated over, so why can't it be modified?

If anyone has any suggestions as to how I can get this to work, or a better way to achieve the same, that'd be great.

Thanks.

Comment: What collection are you testing these on? Since only you seem to get exceptions on the second one, your collection might not even support Remove...

Comment: Heres an extract from a unit test which fails when using this method, where 'mockStaff' is a pre-existing List<Staff>.

Staff newStaff = new Staff{StaffId = 5};
mockStaff.Add(newStaff);
mockStaff.RemoveWhere(s => s.StaffId == 5); //Invalid operation exception thrown here

Comment: Lee: Something else must be going on. See my answer for an example.

Comment: I reverted the method to how it was before, and now it seems to be working like everyone says. Most bizarre. Maybe I'm losing it. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For `List<T>`, this exists already, as `RemoveAll(Predicate<T>)`. As such, I'd suggest that you keep the name (allowing familiarity, and precedence).

Basically, you can't remove while iterating. There are two common options:

- use indexer based iteration (`for`) and removal
- buffer the items to remove, and remove after the `foreach` (as you've already done)

So perhaps:

```
public static void RemoveAll<T>(this IList<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
        if (predicate(list[i])) {
            list.RemoveAt(i--);
        }
    }
}
```

Or more generally for any `ICollection<T>`:

```
public static void RemoveAll<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    T element;

    for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++) {
        element = collection.ElementAt(i);
        if (predicate(element)) {
            collection.Remove(element);
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

This approach has the advantage of avoiding lots of extra copies of the list.

Comment: When I remove from a collection using your first common option I usually store Count in a int n variable and let the loop count back back from the end to the beginning, not needing the i--. Saves a Count() call inside the loop. (Premature optimalisation, I know...)

Comment: @rolls it will break `foreach`, but we aren't using that. The most common option is "iterate backwards", but forwards works too if you compensate when removing

Answer (score 7):

As Marc said, `List<T>.RemoveAll()` is the way to go for lists.

I'm surprised your second version didn't work though, given that you've got the call to `ToList()` after the `Where()` call. Without the `ToList()` call it would certainly make sense (because it would be evaluated lazily), but it should be okay as it is. Could you show a short but complete example of this failing?

EDIT: Regarding your comment in the question, I still can't get it to fail. Here's a short but *complete* example which works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Staff
{
    public int StaffId;
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void RemoveWhere<T>(this ICollection<T> Coll,
                                      Func<T, bool> Criteria)
    {
        List<T> forRemoval = Coll.Where(Criteria).ToList();

        foreach (T obj in forRemoval)
        {
            Coll.Remove(obj);
        }
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Staff> mockStaff = new List<Staff>
        {
            new Staff { StaffId = 3 },
            new Staff { StaffId = 7 }
        };

       Staff newStaff = new Staff{StaffId = 5};
       mockStaff.Add(newStaff);
       mockStaff.RemoveWhere(s => s.StaffId == 5);

       Console.WriteLine(mockStaff.Count);
    }
}
```

If you could provide a similar *complete* example which fails, I'm sure we can work out the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it, and your second method works fine (as it should). Something else must be going wrong, can you provide a bit of sample code that shows the problem?

```
List<int> ints = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

ints.RemoveWhere(i => i > 5);
foreach (int i in ints)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Gets:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your second example and it seems to work fine:

```
Collection<int> col = new Collection<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
col.RemoveWhere(x => x % 2 != 0);

foreach (var x in col)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.ReadLine();
```

I didn't get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Another version of Marcs RemoveAll:

```
public static void RemoveAll<T>(this IList<T> list, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    int count = list.Count;
    for (int i = count-1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        if (predicate(list[i]))
        {
            list.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A) You shouldn't store the Count outside, the compiler cannot remove the bounds check if you do that.

Comment: B) This overload is almost useless, you would have to specifically save your predicate as Func<T, bool> before passing it in otherwise it will satisfy the original RemoveAll<T>(Predicate<T>) and not call your extension.

Comment: A) I know, but can the compiler optimize it even when you remove items in the loop and depend on the count changing?

Comment: More importantly, since it's an interface you have no idea how the Count is implemented, perhaps it's a very expensive call to some database, so I wouldn't trust the compiler to optimize this for me. I agree with B though.