# Remove row from gridview datatable with check box selection in button click event

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

I am trying to delete selected rows from gridview in button click event but I am getting the below error:

> > Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.

**Code:**

```
    protected void btnRemoveUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
      DataTable yourDataTable = GetDataTable(Studentlist);     
      //CheckBox chkbx;
      foreach(GridViewRow oneRow in Studentlist.Rows)
      {
        CheckBox  chkbx = (CheckBox)oneRow.FindControl("ckbxID");
          foreach (DataRow rowDT in yourDataTable.Rows)  **//In this line throwing the exception**
          {
              if (chkbx.Checked == true)
              {
                  yourDataTable.Rows.Remove(rowDT);  
              }

          }  
      }     

      Studentlist.DataSource = yourDataTable;
      Studentlist.DataBind();

  }
```

Note: Studentlist is the gridview ID.

Comment: Dnyanesh said : "You can not remove item from collection while performing foreach on it" that's true,so try to declare another datatable "DataTable newDataTable = yourDataTable;" and remove the rows from newDataTable and finally pass it to datasource

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove item from collection while performing foreach on it for details visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791557/efficiently-deleting-item-from-within-foreach).

For now you can use easy technique to delete items.

```
for(int i = 0; i< yourDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
      if (chkbx.Checked == true)
      {
          yourDataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
      }
  }
```

Comment: I can't see there is `Length()` function in Datatable.Rows , so it should throw compilation error.

Comment: My mistake count will work in this case. Edited answer

Comment: @Dnyanesh:Thanks, for ur reply. Using this technique rows are not deleting properly for ex. if I select 1 row its deleting 2 or 3 rows.

Comment: It is deleting 2 or 3 row is ambiguous. Select only first row in grid and delete it. Result will be it will either it will delete the 1 row or will give some exception try it.

Comment: If I select first row its deleting 3 rows and not throwing any exception.

Comment: I do not see any obvious error in code but as it is deleting 3 rows means chkbx is true for 3 times, and that is something going wrong is what I can think of.